# Programmatically tracking SignalR data usage in a UWP app

Tags: uwp, signalr, signalr.client

I have a UWP app that connects to a server to send and receiver data using SignalR.

I would like to track the amount of data my connections are using (per day).

It would also be acceptable to track all internet usage from the app, so a generic technique rather than targeting SignalR specifically would also be useful.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have looked into implementing a custom `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.IHttpClient` and also network tracing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing - not available on UWP?)

This technique by @Ipsit Gaur works well, I had to modify it slightly though

```
var internetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
if (internetConnectionProfile != null)
{
    var networkUsage = await internetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Date, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DataUsageGranularity.PerDay, new NetworkUsageStates()).AsTask();
    totalBytesSentToday = networkUsage.Aggregate(0ul, (memo, nu) => memo + nu.BytesSent);
    totalBytesReceivedToday = networkUsage.Aggregate(0ul, (memo, nu) => memo + nu.BytesReceived);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you -

```
string localDataUsage = string.Empty;
    DateTime CurrTime = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan TimeDiff = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
    ConnectionProfile InternetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

if (InternetConnectionProfile == null)
{
    LocalUsageData.Text = "Not connected to Internet" + "\n";
}
else
{
    var LocalUsage = InternetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(CurrTime.Subtract(TimeDiff), CurrTime);

    localDataUsage = "Local Data Usage:\n";
    localDataUsage += " Bytes Sent     : " + LocalUsage.BytesSent + "\n";
    localDataUsage += " Bytes Received : " + LocalUsage.BytesReceived + "\n";
    LocalUsageData.Text = localDataUsage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to adjust it slightly but this works great